# Mvvmcross - Best way to retrieve updates

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm not after any code in particular but I want to know what is the most efficient way to build a function that will constantly check for updates for things such as messages e.g. Have a chat conversation window and I want live updates such as Facebook.

Currently I have implemented it by putting a while loop in my core code that checks if the view is currently visible run a Task every 5 seconds to get new messages. This works but I don't believe its the most efficient way to do it and I need to consider battery life. *Note I do change visibility when the view goes away e.g. on iOS i do

```
public override ViewDidDissapper {
 Model.SetVisible(false)
}
```

Has anyone implemented some sort of polling on a cross platform app?

Comment: This isn't really an mvvmcross question - there are lots of other tags that might help get you some really good answers here. It would also help to add what you are requesting updates from - and whether that can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different possible solutions here - which one you prefer depends a lot on your requirements in terms of latency, reliability, efficiency, etc - and it depends on how much you can change server side.

If your server is fixed as a normal http server, then frequent polling may be your best route forwards, although you could choose to modify the 5 seconds occasionally when you think updates aren't likely.

One step up from this is that you could try long polling http requests within your server.

Another step beyond that are using Socket (TCP, UDP or websocket) communications to provide "real time" messaging.

And in parallel to these things, you could also consider using PUSH notifications both within your app and in the background.

Overall, this is a big topic - I'd recommend reading up about PushSharp from @Redth and about SignalR from Microsoft - @gshackles has some blog posts about using this in Xamarin. Also, services like AzureMobileServices, UrbanAirship, Buddy, Parse, etc may help